# Using rollup/svelte/node-polyfills, import and require function differently

Tags: node.js, svelte, rollupjs

```
//this works
const homedir = require('os').homedir;
console.log(homedir())

//this throws "Error: 'homedir' is not exported by polyfill-node.os.js ..."
import {homedir} from 'os'
console.log(homedir())
```

Why would the behavior be different if `import` can reference both ESM and CJS modules?

Relevant rollup config:

```
export default (async ()=>({

  input: 'app/svelte.ts',

  output: {
    sourcemap: !production,
    format: 'iife', //used for loading up JS in a script tag
    file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
  },

  plugins: [
    
    nodePolyfills(),
    
    svelte({
      preprocess: preprocess()
    }),

    commonjs({
      defaultIsModuleExports: true,
      transformMixedEsModules: true
    }),
    
    css({output: 'bundle.css'}),

    typescript(),

    alias({
      entries: [
        {find: /^@pkg\/(.*)/, replacement: 'packages/$1'},
      ],
    }),

    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ['svelte'],
    }),

    !production && serve(),

    !production && livereload('public'),

    json(),
    
  ],

}))()
```

Rollup **plugin order** seems to matter, too, because when i shift `nodePolyfills()` below `resolve()`, the error changes to `Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules os (guessing 'os')`.  I've attempted using the suggested fixes for this including `externals` and `output.globals` in rollup config without any success.